# AHKV1: Send a 'Ctrl+Wheel' to a inactive window with either ControlSend or ControlClick?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this application, [RegExBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/). It lets you change the font size of any of its panels by hovering over the panel, holding `ctrl` down and scrolling `up`/`down`, as shown [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/WjC3vMF.gif).

I want to do this with my keyboard, while the window is inactive. For example if VsCode or Visual Studio is active, I want to increase/decrease RegExBuddy's font size with my keyboard. I solve this kind of problem all of the time with `ControlSend`. Unfortunately RegExBuddy does not have a keyboard shortcut for increasing/decreasing the font size.

More interestingly, it occurred to me it may actually **not** be possible to send  `<modifier>` + `<WheelUp`/`Wheeldown` combinations, such as `ctrl` + `WheelUp`, using `ControlClick`. I determined `ControlSend` being incapable of doing such a thing from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlSend.htm#Parameters):

> Unlike the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm) command, mouse clicks cannot be sent by ControlSend. Use [ControlClick](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlClick.htm) for that.

To start, the following correctly sends a `Wheelwp` to the top panel, the RegEx panel without activating the window:

```
ControlClick, x300 y5, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe,,wu,, NA
```

I tried `^{wu}` but it throws a run time error, `Parameter #4 invalid. Specifically: ^{wu}`:

```
ControlClick, x300 y5, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe,,^{wu},, NA
```

I also tried holding down the modifier before issuing `ControlClick` but this doe not work either, only `WheelUp` is sent, the panel is scrolled up:

```
SendInput, {ctrl down}
Sleep, 50
ControlClick, x300 y5, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe,,wu,, NA
Sleep, 50
SendInput, {ctrl up}
```

Another variation of the above, that also failed to work:

```
;ControlSend, TJGStringEditorControl1, ^{a}, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe ; This works. All test is selected
ControlSend, TJGStringEditorControl1, {ctrl down}, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe
Sleep, 50
ControlClick, x300 y5, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe,,wu,, NA 
Sleep, 50
ControlSend, TJGStringEditorControl1, {ctrl up}, RegexBuddy ahk_exe RegexBuddy4.exe
```

I know people always complain about `Controclick`/`ControlSend` being unreliable but that has been a rare experience for me. They are almost always my go to commands, when I need to control a window in a "programmatic" like way.

I really need a solution for sending something like `Ctrl` + `WheelUp` through `ControlClick`/`ControlSend` or even through other means. Something a go I remember coming across a solution that sent wheel messages to a specific window using `SendMessage` but I never kept it around well...because I figured I was covered by `Controlclick`.

Also can AutoHotkey V2 send `<modifier>` + `<WheelUp`/`Wheeldown` combinations, such as `ctrl` + `WheelUp` with `ControlClick` now? It would be interesting to know for sure.

Thanks for any help.